# How can I get the new window size after an iPad screen rotation?

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, mobile

I am trying to change the size of a  element in a webpage when the user rotates the screen (especially for iPads, but also for all mobile devices). The new size will be calculated based off the new screen dimensions.

I have tried using `window.onresize = myFcn;`, but the resize event doesn't fire correctly on my iPad.

I have tried using `window.onorientationchange = myFcn;`, but the event is fired BEFORE the actual dimensions of the screen change, so I can't use them to figure out the correct new size of the table.

I have tried using `setTimeout(myFcn, 50)` as suggested in an SO answer I read, but that just creates an infinite loop as the dimensions don't change while the loop is running.

How can I get the new screen size AFTER an orientation change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you combine 2 and 3, that would give 50ms for the device to complete its orientation change (which you could increase if it's insufficient).

```
window.onorientationchange = function () {
  setTimeout(myFcn, 50);
};
```

Comment: This worked, although I had to increase the wait to 500ms to get it to consistently use the new size. I'm worried that this will break on certain devices, but it seems to be the best option for now.